# Need to align social media icons with the right side of the page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, icons

Please check this page: http://badadesigns.com/work438/

Here at the top of the page there are social media icons but they are not aligned to the right side of the page. When I am resizing the browser page then the alignment is changing.

I am really not sure what code is being used, but I think this is it:

```
#logincont {
    width:330px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:1145px;
}
```

Can anyone please help me with the alignment so that it is fixed and set along the right side border of the page?

Comment: your theme isn't fully responsive, you are aware of this right?

Comment: and having a margin in px ruins the whole responsive thing, if you need a margin, put it in % or em

Comment: That was very helpful. I will keep it in mind from next time. For now I fixed the issue by following what Drewman suggested. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

div `#logincont` is set to `float:left` and has a huge `margin-left` which is unnecessary.

It should be `float: right` without margin, like this

```
#logincont {
    width:330px;
    float:right;
}
```

**Update** : If I understand correctly, you want the social media icons to be aligned on the right but not further than the content of the site.

Try this :

```
#logincont {
    width: 940px;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

width is set to the width of the `#content` div, the content of `#logincont` is aligned right and `#logincont` itself is centered on the page with `margin: 0 auto`

Comment: Hi. I did this but still the icons are not right-aligned. They are pushed to the far right of the screen

Comment: I'm not sure I uderstand what you mean, i'll update my answer.

Comment: Hey thanks :) It has fixed the issue. I added another div and then set it to 1000px with auto margins. The icons are now right-aligned. The page width is 1000px. I put this div nested inside that... Thanks tons!

Comment: I dont think you need that extra 1000px-large div, see my update. Anyway, glad that it suits your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get all of the content to stay within view try fixing this:

```
#logincont {
postition:absolute;
right:2px;
}
```

Comment: absolute might not work for this case since the page will be resized.

Comment: It stays in the correct place as he is looking for. Even after resizing the browser.

Comment: to explain a little more: it depends on the nearest relatively position parent element, so as long as the container resizes with the page then the absolutely positioned element will remain in the correct place

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
#logincont {
    width:330px;
    float:right;
}
```

Based on your requirements and the type of element you might need to add more properties.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're looking for specifically, but try this:

```
#login {
background: #113240;
color: #DDD;
height: 30px;
padding: 8px;
position: fixed;
z-index: 3;
top: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
}
#logincont {
width: 330px;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
}
#header {
background: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EBEBEC;
padding: 4.429em 0 0;
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
}
```